# Programatically create a region within a frame for a sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a sprite ball that I want to bounce only within a square region.

How can I progrmatically create this square region within my main frame as opposed to constraining the entire frame as I have in my code snippet:

```
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
borderBody.friction = 0
self.physicsBody = borderBody
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet. It creates an SKNode with a SKPhysicsBody. You can then place your sprite in this node:

```
    // Create a boundary rectangle. Adjust with your size:
    let boundary = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)

    // Create a boundary node
    let boundaryNode = SKNode()

    // Create the PhysicsBody and assign it to the node
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: boundary)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    boundaryNode.physicsBody = borderBody

    // Add boundary node to the scene
    self.addChild(boundaryNode)

    // Add your Sprite to the boundaryNode
    boundaryNode.addChild(yoursprite)
```